# display different item from a list on click of a button in MVC Mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list of Customers in my customers list.

```
List<Customer> customers= GetCustomer("New York");
```

I want to display each Customer item in an MVC view on click of Left and right buttons and finally save Customer at the end.

My MVC View as below

> **| LeftButton |  1 of 5  |RightButton|**
>
> **Customer:** Michael
>
> **Address:** 123 Park Ave,
>   New York
>
> **Rating:** 4
>
> **Phone:** 123456
>
> **|ButtonSave| |ButtonRemove|**

I hope i explained it properly, what should be my approach to get this thing done in MVC with partial page updates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

Create a partial view to show single Customer record.

Model:

```
    public static Customer GetCustomerInfo(int customerId)
    {
        using (var db = new DbContext())
        {
            return db.Customers
                .Where(c => c.CustomerId == customerId)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

View:

```
    <label><b>Customer:</b> @ViewBag.Customer.Name</label><br>
    <label><b>Address:</b> @ViewBag.Customer.Address</label><br>
    <label><b>Rating:</b> @ViewBag.Customer.Rating</label><br>
    <label><b>Phone:</b> @ViewBag.Customer.Phone</label>
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult GetCustomer(int customerId)
    {
        var customer = CustomerModel.GetCustomerInfo(customerId);
        return PartialView(customer);
    }
```

On Next and Previous buttons make ajax call to load the partial view html for the appropriate record.

```
    function loadCustomer(customerId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Store/GetCustomer?customerId=' + customerId,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                //Fill in the div where you load the partial view with the result
                $('#customerDiv').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

On Save and Delete buttons make another ajax call to execute the desired operation.

This solution is appropriate if you aspect a lots of records in the database. If not you can cache all the data on the client side and call the server only on Save and Delete. Another solution is to cache 10 records for example and when you reach the 10th record, cache another batch.